react native platform,sdk34 crash on android 14 development but not on launched
My problem is that my app is currently on SDK 34 and it is able to run through Playstore, but doesn't able to run through development mode. On development mode when I open it, it will crash immediately, but from the app on Google Playstore, it is able to run well. This doesn't happen on SDK 33 and below.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/XWdKKnfc.png)
Since it is able to open through Playstore download but not development mode. The Gradle version won't be a big problem there must be another problem I didn't spot.
